# Square bracket ( test condition ) stuff in shell and advance case statement

Tags: shell, testing, if-statement, case, conditional-statements

I have two questions. Lets talk about the simpler one 1st and then we'll talk about the case statement.
consider this simple if else

```
if  fgrep -q '= ' sf
then
echo "blanks in file"
else
echo "no blanks"
fi

[[ `fgrep -q '= ' sf` ]]  && echo "blanks there"
# rc=$?
# echo "rc is $rc"
```

the if condition works like a charm.  I am trying to rewrite the same stuff using `[[` test condition and it does not exactly work. What is wrong in my test condition.

now the 2nd Question

Actually here is what I am trying to do .

There is this kinda case statement I have

```
    source "/path"
    # die is a function that will output standard error and return 1 
    opta=false
    optb=false

while getopts ":abf:" opt; do
  case $opt in
      a ) $optb && die "Cannot specify option a after specifying option b"
          opta=true
          ;;
      b ) $opta && die "Cannot specify option b after specifying option a"
          optb=true
          ;;
      f) # Pl see the note below for f 

      \?) die "Invalid option: -$OPTARG. Abort"
          ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
test $# -eq 0 && die "You must supply SID"
test $# -eq 1 || die "Too many command-line arguments"
SID=$1
```

the f is a file option. So 1st two are incompatible if -f is used.

```
myshell -f /path/file1 -a 500
```

above is not allowed. I can manage this part so don't worry about it too much

Here is the rock that's stumbling me off path .
-f accepts a file path. The file is an manual override file that has various parameters that will override ones set using the source command . So when It comes to f option it should do the following 
check if

1. file  path is valid
  2.

if it is valid check if there IS "= "viz. equal to followed by blank- then quit.In other words I dont want blank values || ones that ^blank

3

if both these conditions are met then if the search string s parameter is set in the file then there cannot be any positional  parameters passed to the command .

e.g.  of manual override file below

```
p1=v1
p2=v2
s=v3
p3=


     # some parameters like p3 need to be set in that case it will take the defaults from   the source file  if those aren't set
```

In other words e.g the below command

myshell.ksh -f /path/file1 500

is valid if value of s is NOT set in file1  else it should quit giving an error that positional parameter was supplied when override value was already applied in file -f file1

4
export all  the parameters that are set in file1 as  overrides to the source file parameters.
e.g. source file has

```
  p1=sv1
```

and in file1 p1 is set then export p1=v1 from file1

I can manage #4. I just need some insight into $3 for the most. 2,1 and 4 won't harm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

The `[[...]]` have no business being there.  Use:

```
fgrep -q '= ' sf && echo "blanks there"
```

The above runs `fgrep` on `sf`.  If `fgrep` indicates success, then the echo command is run.

#### Question 2

If `/path/file1` contains a setting for the `s` variable and there are positional parameters on the command line, then we are supposed to report an error:

```
grep '^s=' /path/file1 && [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && echo "ERROR: file has s parameter set and there are positional arguments"
```

The above checks for two conditions to be true and, if they are both true, it prints an error message.  The first condition is:

```
grep '^s=' /path/file1
```

The is true if the file `/path/file1` has a line that begins with the characters `s=`.  (`^` signifies the beginning of a line.)  The second condition is:

```
[ "$#" -gt 0 ]
```

This return true if the number of positional parameters is greater than zero.  If both of those conditions are true, then the `echo` statement above is executed.

#### Question 2: Alternate Approach

In this case, we suppose that the variable `$filepath` has the path and name of the file, such as `/path/file1`, which contains shell commands for setting variables.  The following checks to see if that file is readable.  If it is, then it sources all the commands in that file.  The next line checks to see if `s` has been set.  If it has and if there are still positional parameters, then it prints a message:

```
[ -r "$filepath" ] && source "$filepath" # Set all override variables
[ -n "$s" ] && [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && echo "message"
```

In the test (`[...]`) statements, note that `$filepath` and `$s` are enclosed in double-quotes.  This prevents an error should either value be empty.  It also prevents errors if the value of `filepath` contains spaces.

To source a file, it needs not merely to exist but also to be readable.  Therefore, the first test above checks for readability (`-r`) instead of mere existence (`-f`).

#### MORE

To check if the source file has any uncommented lines with variables set to empty values:

```
grep -qE '^[^#]+=$' file1 && echo "message"
```

In the above `^` matches the beginning of a line.

The regular expression works because `[^#]` matches any character that is not a hash sign.  Since plus sign means one or more of the preceding character, the `[^#]+` means a string of one or more characters, none of which are hash signs.  Outside of square brackets, a `^` matches the start of a line.  So, `^[^#]+` matches any string of non-hash characters starting at the beginning of the line.  `^[^#]+=` matches if those characters are then followed by an equal sign.  Since `$` matches the end of a line, then `^[^#]+=$` matches if the line starts with one or more non-hash characters, followed by an equal sign, followed by nothing (the end of the line).  Thus, it matches if some variable has its value set to nothing.

Comment: @user1874594 OK.  I have added that to the answer.

Comment: That was v useful indeed.Somehow it does not preclude the scenario that someone could have accidentally unset a comment inside the overrride file. e.g. instead of this `# s=` they'd have uncommented to `s=`. How about this approach. I check if it exists with `[ -f $filepath ]` and then run `source $filepath # exports all my override variables` . Then check if the value is set with the above $# approach. Just like that `[ -n $s ] && [ "$# -gt 0 ] && echo "message"`

Comment: Also I was stuck at testing for that kind of string pattern in the template file. search for this pattern `variable=` that is someone has un-commented out a variable but forgot to assign it a value. I took care of the above  Q #3 with an if statement and checking if $s is set - not in the case but lower down -your approach with $# is very elegant. TY- that will let me add all those 'bouncers' ( 'cos they weed out all unwanted conditions ) at 'case' level.

Comment: @user1874594  Your approach looks good!  I added it to the answer with some minor refinements.

Comment: Also finally I need to hunt down situations like this (actually mentioned earlier) where a variable is ucommented out but the value is not set.So this is allowed `# p3=` since its commented out but this isn't `p3=` `#someone accidentally removed the comment `. I need to catch 1 more more lines like this and throw and error if they exist:  `p3=` `p4=` `p5=`

Comment: @user1874594 I have added that also.

Comment: thanks that makes good regex sense .Just on a 1st hunch-  I wondered what that + sign's doing there.

Comment: @user1874594 Plus signs mean one or more of the preceding characters.  I added more to the regex explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thanks galore. Very helpful